# Replace semicolon with the word present in the same line in python

Tags: python-3.x, regexp-replace

I want my data like `<Prags>87654321</Prags>`,
`<Cookie>2476157</Cookie>` `<Guddu>98765</Guddu>`
My data is like `<Prags>87654321;`
Replace the semicolon with the first word of the sentence.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Given your information, I suppose you have either a file or multiline string with information that you want to process. If your multiline string looks like this:

```py
data = """
<Prags>87654321;
<Cookie>87654321;
<Guddu>87654321;
<Prags>87654321;
<Prags>87654321;"""
```

I would split this string into individual lines and extract the tag using `re` as follows:

```py
# extracting lines
lines = data.splitlines()

# this function looks for tags
# if there are no tags, it returns empty string


def find_tag(line):
    try:
        return re.match("<[^>]*>", line).group()
    except AttributeError:
        return ""


# we then iterate over lines and process them
for line in lines:
    line = line.replace(";", find_tag(line))
    print(line)
```

Do not forget to import `re` package with `import re`.